# Collision detection for tile based game. - Collision when there are more than one tile

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I've been searching for answer to this many, many times, but i didn't found anything.

I am trying to make collision detection in my tile based game. The tile is 32px width and height, and this is how i'm creating the map:

```
function map(){
    var tileset = new Image();
    tileset.src = "images/tileset.png";
    var mapIndexOffset = -1;
    var rows = 16;
    var col = 24;
    var tileMap = [

     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

    ];

    for(mapRows = 0; mapRows < rows; mapRows++){
        for(mapCol = 0; mapCol < col; mapCol++){
            var tileId = tileMap[mapRows][mapCol]+mapIndexOffset;
            var sourceX = tileId * 32;
            var sourceY = 0;
            var tileW = 32;
            var tileH = 32;
            var tileX = mapCol * 32;
            var tileY = mapRows * 32;

            ctx.drawImage(tileset, sourceX, sourceY, tileW, tileH, tileX, tileY, tileW, tileH);

        }
    }
}
```

Then i did something like that(Inside this for loop.):

```
if(tileId == 1){//1 is actually 2
    //collision detection here...
}
```

So, when the **tileId** was 1(2 in the **tileMap** array), there would be collision. And it works, but only when one tile is on the map, when there are more, collision is working only for the last tile.

The player is moving per 3 pixels, not 32, like in many tile based games.

Here is my collision detection code:

```
var leftCollision   = o1x + o1w == o2x && o1y + o1h >= o2y && o1y <= o2y + o2h;
var topCollision    = o1y + o1h == o2y && o1x + o1w >= o2x && o1x <= o2x + o2w;
var rightCollision  = o1x == o2x + o2w && o1y + o1h >= o2y && o1y <= o2y + o2h;
var bottomCollision = o1y == o2y + o2h && o1x + o1w >= o2x && o1x <= o2x + o2w;

if(leftCollision){
    //left collision is true
}else if(rightCollision){
    //right collision is true
}else if(topCollision){
    //top collision is true
}else if(bottomCollision){
    //bottom collision is true
}
```

- **o1** is the player.
- **o2** is the tile.

The player has 32px in width and 48px in height.

Comment: How do you represent an empty tile?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty tile"? Tile without collision?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could call it that. I was assuming that as long as there is any tile, it would cause a collision, but it doesn't have to be. How do you differentiate between tiles that do cause a collision and ones that don't?

Comment: Well, 1 or 2 or something else just determines what graphic it will be on the tile, but i want to have collision on every tile that has number 2. That would be something like that: **if(tileId == 1)**. Keep in mind that 2 in the array, is actually 1 for tileId. BTW: Sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: Yes, why is that? Can't you just use the same number for both? And you haven't shown us what it should collide with - we only have the map and the map isn't going to collide with itself. Also, I do think you should show us your collision code, so we can help you find the problem in it. We're not going to write your code for you, but we can help you solve a problem...

Comment: I can use same number for both, i can just delete mapIndexOf(which is actually -1), and then add -1 to the tileId in the drawImage, no problem. And i am going to edit the question, add collision detection script.

Comment: We'll need a little bit more. The code you have given us so far looks good, and the problem appears like it could well be in the way you connect the collision detection code to the rest of your code. You say `Then i did something like that(Inside this for loop.):` but that's a little too vague. Could you put that into code?

Comment: I found out how to fix it by myself, heh. But thanks for your williness. :)